# c# microsoft graph - how to authenticate without login and password?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm following the flow described in this site https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-restapi/tree/master/Demos/02-create-app.

but when I access the link below

```
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
         client_id={{REPLACE_APPLICATION_ID}}
         &response_type=code
         &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1234
         &response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fcalendars.read
    &state=12345
```

it shows the "choose an account", so I have to define my user and password.

[image]

after this i can get the url with code described (https://localhost:1234/?code=...)

obs: I have no experience with ms graph lib so there is a possibility that I am following the wrong flow. And I need to develop the code in C#, although I see many examples in asp net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

So, you were able to get the url (localhost:1234?code=...) that represents the authorization code. Now you need to use that authorizaton code to request your OAuth2 Access Token. I would say the easiest way is if you reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet) that guides you step by step on how to do it, using c# as you want.

Comment: the problem is that i had to set this user and pass. I wish I didn't have to do this

Comment: So you need to use the authentication without user, so using an app identity - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service